# error mod_ssl requires OpenSSL 0.9.8a or later

Tags: apache, openssl, makefile, solaris

I am trying install apache 2.4.7 in Solaris machine. First  I did the configuration using

./configure

Then, When I do make. after some successful  statements it throws me following error.

```
In file included from mod_ssl.c:27:
ssl_private.h:109:2: #error mod_ssl requires OpenSSL 0.9.8a or later
*** Error code 1
make: Fatal error: Command failed for target `mod_ssl.slo'
Current working directory /var/spool/pkg/httpd-2.4.7/modules/ssl
*** Error code 1
The following command caused the error:
if test `pwd` = "/var/spool/pkg/httpd-2.4.7"; then \
    echo "" ; \
fi; \
list=''; for i in $list; do \
    target="shared-build"; \
    if test "$i" = "."; then \
        made_local=yes; \
        target="local-shared-build"; \
    fi; \
    if test "$i" != "srclib"; then \
        (cd $i && make $target) || exit 1; \
    fi; \
done; \
if test -f 'modules.mk'; then \
    if test -n 'mod_ssl.la'; then \
        echo "Building shared: mod_ssl.la"; \
        if test "$made_local" != "yes"; then \
                make "local-shared-build" || exit 1; \
        fi; \
    fi; \
fi; \
if test `pwd` = "/var/spool/pkg/httpd-2.4.7"; then \
        echo "" ; \
fi
make: Fatal error: Command failed for target `shared-build-recursive'
Current working directory /var/spool/pkg/httpd-2.4.7/modules/ssl
*** Error code 1
The following command caused the error:
if test `pwd` = "/var/spool/pkg/httpd-2.4.7"; then \
    echo "" ; \
fi; \
list='aaa cache core database debugging filters http loggers metadata proxy session slotmem ssl proxy/balancers arch/unix dav/main generators dav/fs mappers'; for i in $list; do \
    target="shared-build"; \
    if test "$i" = "."; then \
        made_local=yes; \
        target="local-shared-build"; \
    fi; \
    if test "$i" != "srclib"; then \
        (cd $i && make $target) || exit 1; \
    fi; \
done; \
if test -f 'modules.mk'; then \
    if test -n ''; then \
        echo "Building shared: "; \
        if test "$made_local" != "yes"; then \
                make "local-shared-build" || exit 1; \
        fi; \
    fi; \
fi; \
if test `pwd` = "/var/spool/pkg/httpd-2.4.7"; then \
        echo "" ; \
fi
make: Fatal error: Command failed for target `shared-build-recursive'
Current working directory /var/spool/pkg/httpd-2.4.7/modules
*** Error code 1
The following command caused the error:
if test `pwd` = "/var/spool/pkg/httpd-2.4.7"; then \
    echo "" ; \
fi; \
list='srclib os server modules support'; for i in $list; do \
    target="shared-build"; \
    if test "$i" = "."; then \
        made_local=yes; \
        target="local-shared-build"; \
    fi; \
    if test "$i" != "srclib"; then \
        (cd $i && make $target) || exit 1; \
    fi; \
done; \
if test -f 'modules.mk'; then \
    if test -n ''; then \
        echo "Building shared: "; \
        if test "$made_local" != "yes"; then \
                make "local-shared-build" || exit 1; \
        fi; \
    fi; \
fi; \
if test `pwd` = "/var/spool/pkg/httpd-2.4.7"; then \
        echo "" ; \
fi
make: Fatal error: Command failed for target `shared-build-recursive'
Current working directory /var/spool/pkg/httpd-2.4.7
*** Error code 1
The following command caused the error:
otarget=`echo all-recursive|sed s/-recursive//`; \
list='  srclib os server modules support'; \
for i in $list; do \
    if test -d "$i"; then \
        target="$otarget"; \
        echo "Making $target in $i"; \
        if test "$i" = "."; then \
                made_local=yes; \
                target="local-$target"; \
        fi; \
        (cd $i && make $target) || exit 1; \
    fi; \
done; \
if test "$otarget" = "all" && test -z 'httpd shared-build '; then \
    made_local=yes; \
fi; \
if test "$made_local" != "yes"; then \
    make "local-$otarget" || exit 1; \
fi
make: Fatal error: Command failed for target `all-recursive'
```

The same above error is coming even after I install latest openssl version.

**OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014**

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably unintentionally trying to link against Oracle's outdated OpenSSL in /usr/sfw/lib. You may need to explicitly specify the path to your copy of OpenSSL 1.0.1f in your httpd configure command, e.g., "--with-ssl=/path/to/openssl".

Comment: I am also facing similar issue. My openssl is installed with "yum"  command,  so there is no specific directory i can give. In that case what should i do.

I dont have any root permissions.

Comment: @Sohan you could try to install from source openssl. There you can specify what folder you will put on `--with-ssl` parameter

Answer (score 3):

I solved this by installing the development package for open ssl: "sudo apt-get install libssl-dev"